# Arquillian with managed Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

Does anyone have a **working configuration** for Aquillian using a managed Tomcat 7? Arquillian fails always after starting Tomcat with the following lines

```
Apr 15, 2014 12:04:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Information: Server startup in 1165 ms
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 3.453 sec <<< FAILURE!
arquillianBeforeSuite(net.sweblog.jerseyplayground.simple.HelloResourceIT)  Time elapsed: 3.328 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
```

Comment: share your config file along with maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a managed Tomcat 7 together with Arquillian you need to replace the original `tomcat-users.xml` with a custom one, like this one here:

```xml
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" 
          roles="manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-gui"/>
    <user username="masterofdesaster" password="letmein" 
          roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Important for the setup is the second to last line there I defined the user `masterofdesaster` with his own password.

Furthermore you must configure Arquillian via `arquillian.xml`. My one looks like this and uses the user `masterofdesaster` to perform the deployment during my tests:

```xml
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian 
                               http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="tomcat7" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="catalinaHome">/path/to/tomcat7</property>

            <property name="jmxPort">8089</property>
            <property name="bindHttpPort">8080</property>

            <property name="user">masterofdesaster</property>
            <property name="pass">letmein</property>
            <property name="serverConfig">server.xml</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```